# Razor, asp.net, C#: how to validate a form field that is required and allows HTML snippets?

Tags: c#, validation, razor

I am using Razor do a single proof-of-concept cshtml page, no controller. I use ASP.NET 4.5.

This page has a form. Its action points to this page too. So when the form is submitted, it goes to the same page.

The form has a field called "description". It is a required field, but allow users to enter html snippets.

I have the following to check user input:

```
Validation.RequireField("description", "Description is required.");
```

However, when a user enters html snippets in the "description" field and submits the form, the website shows the following error message:

```
    A potentially dangerous Request.Form value was detected from the client (Description="<p>This bilingual.....
....
Line 43:             description = Request.Form["description"];
.....
```

This page is in a VERY safe environment and so html snippets are allowed.

Let's put best practices aside. How can I make the description field required and allow html snippets at the same time? I have more than one field in the form that allow html snippets.

I hope to find a solution that does not touch web.config.

Regards and thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried the solution suggested by mxmissle, it did not work for me. I have just a single cshtml page which has a form as well as the post processing code.

I read many online posts, but unable to find one that works for me. Eventually, I tried something so simple that works. Instead of using

```
description = Request.Form["description"];
```

use

```
description = Request.Unvalidated["description"];
```

The later get the user input with html tags without any runtime complaint. Also

```
Validation.RequireField("description", "Description is required.");
```

still works.

Interestingly enough, I found so many online posts about this error message and none of them  talks about Request.Unvalidated. I am not sure what I did is the right way, but it works for me. If anybody knows a better way, please let me know.

Hope this helps someone else.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you simply add following attribute to your model property.

```
[AllowHtml]
MyHtml
```

Comment: Thanks for chiming in!!! It does not work in my case. I dont any have model object on this page. The form values are simply retrieved via Request.Form["description"].

Answer (score 0):

Add the following to your controller class:

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateInput(false)]
```

or

```
[HttpGet]
[ValidateInput(false)]
```

Just remember that by doing this, you are opening yourself up to attacks. So be sure you have taken the appropriate steps to make your site secure.

Comment: Thanks for your input. I don't have any controller class. Everything I has is just the single page.

Comment: I don't understand. Are you saying you have just a view and nothing else?

Comment: The processing code is in the same page. Yes, just a view. This is a single page proof-of-concept. I dont have layers.

Answer (score 0):

Not recommended but adding this to your `web.config` should do the trick.

```
<system.web>
  <httpRuntime requestValidationMode="2.0" />
</system.web>
```

Comment: Here is what I have now after adding yours. <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" requestValidationMode="2.0"  />. I still get the same error.

Comment: I didnt think think this would anything to do with Razor but also try adding `<pages validateRequest="false" />` to the system.web section.

Comment: I googled and I did both of what you said. No success.